# Julia Package dependencies in Travis CI

Tags: julia, travis-ci

I am trying to use Travis on a package of mine (`UnivariateFunctions`) that depends on another package (`SchumakerSpline`). The build always fails, apparently because it cannot access `SchumakerSpline`. `SchumakerSpline` can be installed from github to my local machine via REPL so it is not clear what the problem with this package is.

What can cause an error of this sort and more generally what are the required steps for using Travis to test a Julia package that is dependent on other Julia packages? What do you need to do with a package to ensure it can be easily referenced and depended on by other packages?

The full error message is below:

```
ERROR: Unsatisfiable requirements detected for package SchumakerSpline [65e68595]:
     SchumakerSpline [65e68595] log:
     ├─possible versions are: 0.0.1 or uninstalled
     ├─restricted to versions 0.0.1-* by UnivariateFunctions [117ba14f], leaving only versions 0.0.1
     │ └─UnivariateFunctions [117ba14f] log:
     │   ├─possible versions are: 0.0.0 or uninstalled
     │   └─UnivariateFunctions [117ba14f] is fixed to version 0.0.0
     └─restricted by julia compatibility requirements to versions: uninstalled — no versions left
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
restricted by julia compatibility requirements
```

means that the package (`SchumakerSpline`) does not support the Julia version you are running.

Answer (score 1):

It seem that the developer of SchumakerSpline did not jet make a new release for Julia 1.0. You might want to make an issue on their repo. Beside this you can also use `Pkg.clone` on Travis CI to have the latest version of SchumakerSpline (which seems to support 1.0).